# What are Telegram bot rate limits aggregation period

Tags: telegram-bot

Telegram limits the message thread on rates mentioned on [FAQ](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this)

> If you're sending bulk notifications to multiple users, the API will
> not allow more than 30 messages per second or so. Also note that your
> bot will not be able to send more than 20 messages per minute to the
> same group.

But it is not clear what is aggregation period for rates to calculate. E.g. would it be acceptable within two seconds to send |0|60| messages which would be still 30 mps?